# Calculate Expectation of of Random variable

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following task:

The probability space $\left([0,5], \mathcal{B}([0,5]), \lambda_{1} / 5\right)$ and the random variable $X(\omega) = I_{[0,1]}(\omega)-2 I_{[2,4]}(\omega)$. Then $\mathbb{E}(X)$:

I am getting $2/5$ , however I am not sure this is correct answer. Would you give me a hint how to approach this task.

Comment: Expectation is linear, and the expectation of an indicator of a measurable set is the probability of that set. These are all the hints you need here. How did you get $\frac{2}{5}$ by the way? How did you try to find the expectation?

Answer (score 1):

We compute
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega)\ \mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega) = \int_0^1 \frac15\ \mathsf dx - 2\int_2^4 \frac15 \ \mathsf dx = -\frac35,
$$
or from first principles,
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega)\ \mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega) = \mathbb P([0,1]) - 2\cdot\mathbb P([2,4]) = \frac15 - 4\cdot\frac15 = -\frac35.
$$

Comment: Thank you , your explanation was very helpful in understanding these type of questions